# Can you cause a function to trigger on any .blur event?

Tags: javascript

I want to make the below function trigger anytime a blur event happens. The end goal is that anytime you click outside the textbox made in the below code, it puts you back in the text box. EXCEPT when you click into a dropdown box. The problem is that the below only works while in the original textbox. As it is now, once you're in a dropdown, you have free reign to click anywhere.

```js
this.textbox = $('<input class="full-width" type="text" tabindex=1/>'); //Change the tab index number to the position you need it to be

this.host.append(this.textbox);


var _this = this;

this.textbox.blur(async function() {
 await sleep(1);
  if (!document.activeElement.className.match("dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has-arrow DropDownBoxes")) {
    _this.textbox.focus();
    _this.textbox.select();
  }
});

function sleep(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, duration * 250)
  })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has- arrow DropDownBoxes" style="font-family:Roboto;font-size:25px;color:Black;;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;;height:100%" tabindex="-1">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you didn't need jquery at all.

```js
var textbox = document.getElementsByClassName("dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has- arrow DropDownBoxes")[0];
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(evt){if(event.target!=document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0]){textbox.focus();}})
```

```css
html, body {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:4px;box-sizing:border-box;}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has- arrow DropDownBoxes" style="font-family:Roboto;font-size:25px;color:Black;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;height:100%;" tabindex="-1">
<select class="dropdown">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Note that I didn't remove the class names, since I wasn't sure what they were for. Also, when I ran the snippet it looked like there was just a text box and nothing else, so I added the dropdown for demonstration purposes.

What the code does is very simple - since click events propagate from the element to its parents, I just added a listener on the document's body for a click. After that, the script just checks if the original clicked element is the dropdown or not, and if it isn't, it focuses back on the textbox.

To be honest, I don't know what you were trying to do with `this`, since it always has to refer to an object (whether an element, or a function, or a variable). So, I just tried to solve your problem directly rather than try versions of your code.

Also, select and format has to be triggered from a click event from a user in most browsers, or it won't work (because if it did, just imagine how spam websites can abuse it and to what level).